# How to replace GRUB with BURG without overwriting MBR?

Tags: grub2, burg

I'd like to install BURG but I don't want it to overwrite my MBR. That's because I've got two bootloaders in my system :

- Default Windows 7 in MBR
- Grub in /dev/sda2

With the first power button, it will boot into Windows and with the second button it boots from /dev/sda2, loading Grub and then Kubuntu.

Now I want to replace GRUB with BURG. I've installed Burg with

```
burg-install /dev/sda2 --force
```

because I don't want my MBR to be overwritten (pressing the first power button MUST load Windows and avoid showing any sign of Linux).

Setup was completed without errors, If I open burg-manager it loads my settings, allowing me to change them and to test everything with burg-emu, so I've changed my settings but the second power button still loads GRUB (Even a different version from the default Kubuntu one).

How can I replace GRUB that's on /dev/sda2 with BURG and without overwriting MBR?

Comment: Everything seems to be ok with what you've done. Are you sure your second power button refers to /dev/sda2?

Comment: It does!
Yesterday I updated to 12.04 and, while waiting for the update to complete, I've found out that the second power button called `/boot/grub/core.img`, so I've changed it to `/boot/burg/core.img` and it seems to work now !